# tmux-resurrectでセッションを復帰させると固まります

Tags: tmux

ターミナルを開いた時にtmuxを自動起動できるようになると聞いてtmux-resurrectを入れてみました。しかし、セッションを復帰させると固まります。

症状としては、入力を一切受け付けなくなる、ただし `prefix Ctrl-q` などは受け付けるので完全に固まってるのではない。カーソルももちろん動かない。

どうしたらターミナルを開いた時にtmux-resurrectで自動的にターミナル終了前の環境を、フリーズさせずに、再現できるのでしょうか?よろしくお願いします。